# Redirect to login page after cookie expires in angularJS

Tags: angularjs, cookies

How to redirect user to login page after angular cookies has expired ? however i've used angualrJS and ngCookies
cookies will expire after one minute as the following

```
$cookiesProvider.defaults.expires = new Date(now.setMinutes(now.getMinutes() + 1));`
```

Am i should user $watch function as the following:

```
$rootScope.$watchCollection($cookies.getObject('user'), function (newVal, oldval) {

       if (newVal != oldval) {
           $rootScope.$broadcast(AuthStatus.session_timeout);
           //console.log(newVal, oldval);
        } else {
           //console.log(newVal, oldval);
       }`
```

Comment: Please follow http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting before editing/posting your questions

Answer (score 1):

I guess it is a authentication cookie. So, it is better that you check the expiration time when you gonna use the cookie. It is not a good idea to abuse of watcher because of performance.

You can do that using a interceptor, for example:

```
angular.module('myModule')
.config(function($httpProvider) {
     $httpProvider.interceptors.push('CookieInterceptor')
})
.factory('CookieInterceptor', function() {
     return {
          'request': function(config) {
                // check if your cookie has expired and
                // $window.location.href = '/login'
          }
     }
});
```

If are not on a SPA, perform the redirect on server-side.

Answer (score 0):

you should use ui-router module.

inject in your code $state and add this line inside your if.

```
if (newVal != oldval) {
   $rootScope.$broadcast(AuthStatus.session_timeout);
   $state.go('login');
   //console.log(newVal, oldval);
}
```

in you main.js import the module ui-router and define the above state togheter with the route that should follow.

```
$stateProvider
.state('login', {
    url: '/login',
    templateUrl: 'login.html',
    controller: 'loginCtrl'
})
.state('somethingElse', {
    url: '/somethingElse',
    templateUrl: 'somethingElse.html',
    controller: 'somethingElseCtrl'
});

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/somethingElse');
```